# D3.js - Appending or Inserting an element depending on the current datum

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is it possible in d3.js to either append or insert a new element depending on the current datum?

I put an example together to demonstrate what I want to achieve

http://jsfiddle.net/DorjeDuck/uDBau/

Basically new red circles are always drawn on top of all blue circles and new blue ones always put below all red ones.

This is so far achieved by filtering the data set (javascript array filter, not the d3 filter). The filter function:

```
var selectNewOnesByColor = function (selection, color) {
    return selection.data(data.filter(function (d) {
        return d.color === color;
    }), function (d) {
        return d.id;
    })
        .enter();
}
```

Subsequently the circles are appended for the one subset and inserted for the other. While this works I was wondering if there is a more direct way to achieve this.

thanks

martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach of filtering the data to achieve two distinct enter selections is the right way to go.  Here's a thread about this very topic (which links to two other interesting threads): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/PKsknGxmZ8g/ULxwneU00J4J.

In one of the sub-threads there is an example showing the use of `selection.select` with a function that returns a newly appended or inserted node.  This is actually how `selection.append` and `selection.insert` are implemented internally so if you really want to consolidate the node creation into a single data bind pass you could potently use this.  The function gets handed the current datum and will use whatever node you return as the node in the selection element.

But I think what you're doing with the pre-filtering is more straight forward.

Comment: Great, thanks Scott for the answer and the link. As Mike himself says in that discussion "prefiltering is the way to go" no need to think further about it I assume ... thanks again